# Microphone not working, Sennheiser headset HD 4.40 Bluetooth, on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, headset

I have connected a Sennheiser headset HD 4.40 Bluetooth to Ubuntu 20.04 but its microphone is not working.  I can see it on the audio configuration window but the test bar does not move at all, it does not detect any audio.  The headphones are working OK.

I am using a Plugable USB 2.0 Bluetooth adapter:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Which audio profile are you using A2DP or HSP? A2DP doesn't support microphone, HSP quality is crap.

Comment: I have tried with both profiles, none of them work.

Comment: Same issue here, I installed aptX, LDAC and none of them work. When I switch my mic from internal to the headsets, my headsets switches to mono and stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by unpairing ("Remove device") the headset and pairing it again.  Initially Ubuntu microphone test bar did not move at all, but I tried in an application and the mic worked, and when going back to Ubuntu sound window the mic bar was detecting sound.